# Microsoft Word cuts off text

Tags: microsoft-word, mathtype

I have Word document with some mathematical text. It contains a lot of Math Type equations. When printed, some rows in text are partially cut off from bottom side, and for example subscript letters and numbers, and also lover parts of some letters in rows, are not visible.

I tried virtually everything: to copy text into a new document, to copy that specific text from other documents, to type it again, to save document in different formats, to change size of equations,...
Also, header lines on some pages are not visible, but I solved that by increasing spacing.

It is indicative that, when i click on header, the text is shown in different colors, and that problematic parts are in lighter shade. Obviously, Word treats these parts of text in different way.

This document is actually one chapter of some material. I created several chapters before this, with same formatting, and there was no problems.

I suspect that equations and their formatting cause problems. Like there are some objects covering these parts of the text.

Here are pictures of same text: how it looks in PDF, and how it looks in Word, when I enter header.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWlqI.png)    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndx02.png)

Comment: You will need to post an example.

Comment: I seems there is something in the header that overlaps the content. You could try to delete everything from the header - go to the header, select all (press `CTRL`+`A`), and then press delete `Delete`. The repeat with the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your paragraph settings as described here: http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tsn/tsn151.htm. Let us know whether that helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I solved the problem. Some parts of text had color behind it, which actually can not be seen until you try to put color behind text (option "Shading"). You can see on the picture, how it looks when you try to color whole text. These parts of the text are not colored, because they already have their color, and that is visible now. The solution is to mark these parts and select option "No Color".Anyway, thank you for your suggestions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDUbX.png)

Comment: Hi User, please go to [contact](https://superuser.com/contact) and ask to merge your accounts [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous)